# Loading /wp-content/uploads/site as /site/

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I love websites so much that I want to put a website into another website. I have a static site under `/wp-content/uploads/site`. It has a lot of pages and I can access it without an issue in `https://[my-domain]/wp-content/uploads/site` but I want it accessible as a root directory: `https://[my-domain]/site`

I tried adding the following rule to my .htaccess:

`RewriteRule ^site/(.*)$ /wp-content/uploads/site/$1 [L]`

This works because I can load the static site as `https://[my-domain]/site` but when I click on links (absolute URLs such as `/site/url` I get redirected to `https://[my-domain]/wp-content/uploads/site/url`

BTW: I added my rule right before `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]`

Any ideas on what's not working?

Comment: is the static site dependent from the main site?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you placed the site in the uploads folder? You can simply move it to your domain's root directory (inside the _site_ folder) to achieve your desired path. Is that not an option?

Comment: @Manyang thanks for your answer, it is not. They're completely independent of each other.

Comment: @WSU interesting... I didn't considered that because I thought it may make the structure a little "clumsy". By default, I like to put "storage" items in the upload folder and then create a redirection.

Comment: Well, it is the simplest solution I can offer. It would also make the subsite easier to reach.